# Find the highest and the lowest value of the function

Tags: functions, trigonometry

$y=1+\sin x \cos x$

Please dont use the formula $2\sin x \cos x=\frac{1}{2}\sin 2x$. We have't learnt it yet.
The key is to return it into an inequation for example $-1 \le \sin x \le 1$

Then multiply with something to give an inequality
For example find the highest and lowest value of $y=\frac{1}{2}\sin x$

$$-1 \le \sin x \le 1$$

$$-\frac{1}{2} \le\frac{1}{2}\sin x \le \frac{1}{2}$$
The highest value is $\frac{1}{2}$, the lowest is $-\frac{1}{2}$
Could you solve $y=1+\sin x\cos x$ in this way after you have done equivalent changes?

Comment: You can differentiate $y$ with respect to $x$ to find stationary points, then take the second derivative to see which of these stationary points are maximum points. Substituting one of these maximum points in will give you the highest value. Similar for the lowest value.

Comment: @IrregularUser We haven't learnt derivates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We want to maximize/minimize $(\sin x)(\cos x)$, or equivalently $2(\sin x)(\cos x)$. Note that 
$$2\sin x\cos x=(\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x)-(\sin x-\cos x)^2=1-(\sin x-\cos x)^2.$$
This attains a maximum  when $(\sin x-\cos x)^2$ is as small as possible, namely $0$.

For the minimum, use the same idea, and
$$2\sin x\cos x=(\sin x+\cos x)^2 -(\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x).$$

Comment: Could you show that using the example method I showed?

Comment: @prishila Your "method" can't be used here because we are dealing with the product of functions. In particular, $a\le f\left(x\right)\le b,\:c\le \:g\left(x\right)\le \:d\:$ does not imply $ac\le f\left(x\right)g\left(x\right)\le bd$.

Comment: @irregular User 42 Ok but could you tell me how can I show that -1/2 is the lowest and 3/2 is the highest value?

Comment: I don't see a quick way of pushing it through your way. At some time we have to use some relationship between sine and cosine. Another way is to consider the square $\sin^2 x\cos^2 x=\sin^2 x-\sin^4 x=u-u^2$ where $u=\sin^2 x$. Then we can complete the square, $u-u^2=(1/4)-(u-1/2)^2$.

Comment: Could you give a detailed explanation? I am not understanding this solution. Where does the -1/2 or 3/2  come out? Maybe you are taking as valid sth I haven't learnt yet.

Comment: I am only using stuff you know by now. From the first displayed equation, we have $2\sin x\cos x\le 1$, and therefore $\sin x\cos x\le \frac{1}{2}$ and thefore $1+\sin x\cos x\le \frac{3}{2}$. From the second displayed equation we can see that $2\sin x\cos x\ge -1$.

Comment: @AndréNicolasThank you very much

Comment: You are welcome. As I mentioned in a comment, there are other ways, such as completing the square.